# Unicode in HTML newsletter subject

Tags: html, unicode, newsletter

I'm preparing a newsletter in Chinese and I'm therefore converting all text to unicode to minimize viewing problems. However, the receiving email clients are showing the unicode representations instead of the characters in the subject line, i.e.:

```
&#21697;&#20840;&#26032;&#32593;
```

etc.

For the contents, everything is working correctly.

I've set

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and so on but can't get it working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the many Unicode symbols will render consistently in every possible mail user agent your subscribers use for viewing their emails. Also not only with regards to the email header fields like subject line sender name. This restriction also equally applies for UTF-8 character encoding and using HTML entities in the email body. 
If you want to put non-ASCII characters in subject lines, i can only tell you that it will  not work reliably.

For example:

```
iPhone does not support any Chinese characters in its email interface.
```

But...

```
Safari support Chinese character in email Subject line but not in the email body.
```

Have a read at **[HERE](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2994/using-html-symbol-entities-in-email/)** and **[HERE](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/outlook-chinese-display.htm)**

Hope this will help you a bit... Good luck